# Daemon spamming system.log and daemon.log

Tags: logs, syslog

I'm having an issue with a specific daemon filling up `daemon.log` and `system.log` in minutes. The lines spammed are:

`Mar  6 05:07:32 lin openconnect[2309]: Connect UDP socket#012: Bad address`

I'm not looking to troubleshoot the issue with `openconnect` at this time, or to fix this using `logrotate`. I just want to know if there's a way to ban a specific process from logging into `syslog/daemon.log`.

Comment: If you use `rsyslog` for your syslog needs, then you can add filters. Otherwise you need to find some way of telling openconnect not to log such issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up setting a filter to prevent logging this messages with the following line on top of /etc/rsyslog.conf

```
:msg, contains, "Connect UDP socket" ~
```